# Convert command-line commands from one tool to another in notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I have a script with lots of lines like this:

```
ss Get $/%SS_SOURCE_PROJECT%/DLL/Vim25Service2005.dll -I-Y -R -VL%2
ss Get $/%SS_SOURCE_PROJECT%/97AUTO/*.* -I-Y -R -VL%2
```

We're migrating from one tool to another (VSS -> TFS) and need to port this script. Lines like the former (get individual file) should be transformed to:

```
tf get . Vim25Service2005.dll /all /version:L%2
```

While the latter (get a directory recursively) should be transformed to:

```
tf get 97Auto /all /recursive /version:L%2
```

Can I automate this with a couple of smart find & replace commands in notepad++, maybe using regex?

Answer (score 1):

**For the first line:**

Find: `.*\$.*/([^\*]*) *-I *-Y *-R *-V *(.*)`

Replace: `tf get . $1 /all /version:$2`

**For the second line:**

Find: <strike>`.*\$.*/\*\.\* *-I *-Y *-R *-V *(.*)`</strike>

`.*\$.*/(.*)/\*\.\* *-I *-Y *-R *-V *(.*)`

Replace: <strike>`tf get . /all /recursive /version:$1`</strike>

`tf get $1 /all /recursive /version:$2`

These regexes address possible lack of or extra whitespace between your arguments, but they do expect your arguments to be in the order you specified (i.e. -I, -Y, -R, -V).  If your arguments are not always in that order we will have to get a bit more creative.

Tested in [Notepad++ 6.3.3](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.3.3.html)

If you need/want to try and tweak it some I recommend using the [gskinner regex tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/).  It is excellent for rapid prototyping regexes.

Comment: Works great but darn it, I realised I made a mistake in the 2nd one... the "97Auto" needs to be used in the replace text... I guess this means using grouping which is definitely beyond my regex skills!

Comment: I adjusted the second regex for you.  When you want to make a group in regex you just use parenthesis then access that group with the `$1`, `$2`, `...`, `$n`.